# How to pass points into cvBoundingRect() in OpenCV?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

The `cvBoundingRect()` function can return the minimum bounding rectangle when I pass it a sequence of points as a `CvSeq*` structure, e.g. like I get from `cvFindContours()`.

However when I want to find the minimum bounding rectangle enclosing two points (that I have as `CvPoint` structures) the function is not accepting the arguments. How to make two `CvPoint` structures into a format acceptable by `cvBoundingRect()`?

**edit:**
((just putting in the code))

```
CvSeqWriter writer;
cvStartWriteSeq( CV_32SC2, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), storage, &writer );
CV_WRITE_SEQ_ELEM( pt1, writer );
CV_WRITE_SEQ_ELEM( pt2, writer );
CvSeq* seq_pt = cvEndWriteSeq( &writer ); //two corners-pts in a seq

rect_pt = cvBoundingRect( seq_pt, 0 ); //rect_pt is a CvRect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html#cvseq) is a page that describes operations on cvSeqs. It has a function to create one, and then a function to push a point on to it, which you can call twice. cvBoundingRect() can then take that cvSeq as a parameter.